# 2D array initialization python

Tags: python

Whey aren't the two of these the same in python `3.7.1`?

1.

```
all = [[]] * 10
all[3].append(33)

> [[33], [33], [33], [33], [33], [33], [33], [33], [33], [33]]
```

2.

```
all = [[] for i in range(10)]
all[3].append(33)
> [[], [], [], [33], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Initially, I tried the first one while expecting the output from the second one but surprisingly this doesn't happen. Any clue why the same reference is initialized in the first snippet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: @MikeScotty true, sorry and thanks.